# Can i continue editing with shell window open in another pane?

Tags: vim

After running `:shell`, I must exit the shell to continue editing.  Can I make the shell window stay in another VIM window produced by `vsplit` and I can continue editing.

Comment: No built-in support in vim. Try eshell in emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) plugin. It can't do everything your shell can but it may be enough to suit your needs. Note that Vim's author is against the idea of an integrated shell, though.